# Can't initiate jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I used to use ipython notebook before it was called Jupyter. However, when I tried to open that again (I have already updated all the ipython and python), the interface looks so weird like this [image]

I also tried to install jupyter following the instruction online but I can't initiate it at all. Any idea about how to fix it? [image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. To fix the immediate issue, I ran:

`python setup.py install`

However, this points to a more pressing problem; your installation is missing dependencies. At the time, I resolved the problem by restarting the installation with a few changes:

- using Python 3
- running `pip install iPython` and `pip install iPython[notebook]`
- *then* running dev quickstart

However, my CS professor recommended using Anaconda instead: http://continuum.io/downloads

Comment: actually i solved the problem by reinstalling ipython notebook...thanks!

Comment: yes, install Anaconda as it provides a much more stable and sandboxed way to use Python, libraries and Jupyter etc.